# How do I alias jQuery to $ before loading a remote library?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use Bootstrap autocomplete in my module. I added this to my .libraries.yml.

```yaml
bootstrap-autocomplete:
  remote: https://bootstrap-autocomplete.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
  version: 2.3.7
  license:
    name: MIT
    url: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/about/license/
    gpl-compatible: true
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
  js:
    https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/xcash/bootstrap-autocomplete@v2.3.7/dist/latest/bootstrap-autocomplete.min.js: { type: external, minified: true, async: true, defer: true }
```

I get this in the HTML markup, which looks fine (until the tests prove otherwise, of course).

```html
<script src="/CLS/core/assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js?v=3.5.1"></script>
[...]
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/xcash/bootstrap-autocomplete@v2.3.7/dist/latest/bootstrap-autocomplete.min.js"></script>
```

On page loading I get the classic *Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function*. Of course, as I well know, `jQuery` is not aliased to `$` in Drupal if called outside the usual closures.

I know [I shouldn't alias jQuery to $ in the global namespace](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/2682/86789), but I cannot think of any better solution.

Is there a solution I should use?

Comment: Are you sure just including the library is causing this error? Often libraries don't do anything until you have some local javascript initializing the library like `$('.my_input_field').autoComplete();`. In the latter case, move that local code inside a [Drupal behavior](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview)

Comment: @Hudri, I guess you are right, I did a quick check repeating what I wrote yesterday and I didn't get the error, so I guess that when I got it I had an instantiation in place. I am using the past because after realizing that bootstrap-autocomplete is not part of the bootstrap core and that I was entering dependency hell I switched to a custom autocomplete implementation, so I no longer have the problem anyway...